# See keepalive and maxclients currently being used?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I know I can set the `maxclients` and `keepalive` on or off in the apache2.conf file, but is there a way to see what settings Apache is currently using for keepalive and maxclients?

The reason is I changed the settings and rebooted the server, but I don't know if Apache is using the new settings or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check for keepalive using curl command

`curl -I http://127.0.0.1`

If it's enabled, you'll see: `Connection: keep-alive`

for the maxclients, this should be available from status module:

`a2enmod status`

and visit `http://127.0.0.1/status` which should be the default location for it.